# User can't be blankの解消方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

いまTwitterのようなサイトを作っています。 
つぶやきの投稿画面に文字を入力し保存ボタンを押したら、1件のエラー: 
User can't be blankと表示されます。 
ユーザーの新規登録画面を作成し、そこにユーザー情報を入力し、正常ログインしたあとのエラーで、Userが空である訳がないのですが。。。 
notes_controller.rbのどこかに異常があるということなのでしょうか？ 
（tweetをnoteと読んでいます） 
notes_controller.rb

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController 
  before_action :authenticate_user! 
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update] 
  before_action :set_note,only:[:show,:edit,:update,:destroy]

  def create 
      @note = Note.new(note_params) 
    if @note.save 
      redirect_to @note,notice:'投稿が保存されました' 
    else 
      @notes = Note.all.order(created_at: :desc) 
      render 'home/top' 
      end 
  end

  def show 
      @notes = Note.find(params[:id]) 
  end
def edit 
    @notes = Note.find(params[:id]) 
  end

  def update 
    if @note.update(note_params) 
      redirect_to @note, notice: "投稿が更新されました" 
    else 
      render :edit 
    end 
  end

  def destroy 
    @note.destroy 
    redirect_to notes_path 
  end

  def liking_users 
    @users = @note.liking_users 
  end

   private

    def set_note 
      @note = Note.find(params[:id]) 
    end

    def note_params 
      params.require(:note).permit(:content) 
    end

    def correct_user 
 note = Note.find(params[:id]) 
      # noteを投稿したユーザーを取得し、current_user?メソッドの引数に渡してください 
      if !current_user?(note.user) 
        redirect_to root_path, alert: '許可されていないページです' 
      end 
    end

end
```

notes_controller.rb

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController 
  before_action :authenticate_user! 
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update] 
  before_action :set_note,only:[:show,:edit,:update,:destroy]
 def create 
      @note = Note.new(note_params) 
    if @note.save 
      redirect_to @note,notice:'投稿が保存されました' 
    else 
      @notes = Note.all.order(created_at: :desc) 
      render 'home/top' 
      end 
  end

  def show 
      @notes = Note.find(params[:id]) 
  end

  def edit 
    @notes = Note.find(params[:id]) 
  end

  def update 
    if @note.update(note_params) 
      redirect_to @note, notice: "投稿が更新されました" 
    else 
      render :edit 
    end 
  end

  def destroy 
    @note.destroy 
    redirect_to notes_path 
  end

  def liking_users 
    @users = @note.liking_users 
  end

 private

    def set_note 
      @note = Note.find(params[:id]) 
    end

    def note_params 
      params.require(:note).permit(:content) 
    end

    def correct_user 
      note = Note.find(params[:id]) 
      # noteを投稿したユーザーを取得し、current_user?メソッドの引数に渡してください 
      if !current_user?(note.user) 
        redirect_to root_path, alert: '許可されていないページです' 
      end 
    end

end
```

noteのmodelのnote.rb

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base 
    belongs_to :user 
    has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy 
    has_many :liking_users, through: :likes, source: :user

validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 } 
    validates :user_id, presence: true 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user_id` (`user`) に代入している部分が見当たりません。おそらく Devise を使っていると思いますが、無関係のモデルに自動的に代入する機能はありません。

`@note = Note.new(note_params)` の直後で、その値を確認してみると `user_id` は `nil` になっているはずです。その直後に次のようなコードを入れれば期待通りに動作するはずです。

```
@note.user = current_user
```